# How to assign IPv4 addresses to LAN clients on OpenWrt?

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, openwrt, ipv4

I flashed my router with OpenWrt and while WiFi devices receive IPv4 addresses, LAN [wired] devices receive IPv6 addresses. I am new to networking and not familiar with IPv6, so I would like to avoid using it within the internal network (being a small home network, we do not need such a complicated setup).

How do I configure OpenWrt's DHCP server to lease IPv4 addresses to both WiFi and wired LAN clients?

Comment: Your description is a little unclear, but are you perhaps talking about [DS-Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#Dual-Stack_Lite_(DS-Lite))? // Also note that IPv4 and IPv6 are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I edited a bit the question

Comment: Which version of OpenWRT are you using?

Comment: Local interfaces should have an IPv6 address, but if you don't want devices to be assigned an IPv6 address, disable the IPv6 DHCP server in [`/etc/config/dhcp`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp) _(under `config dhcp '<interface>'` remove lines `dhcpv6 'server'`, `ra 'server'`, and `ra_management '1'`)_ or via LuCI: Network → Interfaces → <interface> → DHCP Server → IPv6 Settings

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer on the OpenWRT forum. Here was the decision:

```
uci set 'dhcp.lan.dhcpv6=disabled'
uci commit dhcp
/etc/init.d/odhcpd stop; /etc/init.d/odhcpd disable; /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```